# How many control variables can I use in experiment / observational study without overfitting?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, least-squares, fixed-effects-model

Suppose I run a regression looking at the correlation of a training program on wages and I include dummies for different levels of for age, education and industry:

$$
wage_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 program_i + \sum_j \alpha_j age_j + \sum_k \gamma_k education\_level_k + \sum_l \eta_l industry_l + \epsilon_i
$$

Suppose $j=10$, $k=5$ and $l = 50$.

I know that I need a large enough "treatment" and "control" group to detect the effects. And I know to avoid overfitting I want to have enough observations for each estimated coefficient for the controls (say more than 10 for each age, educational level and industry). But do I need to have an equal representation of program participants and non-participants in each age, educational and industry category for the estimate of $\beta_1$ to be credible (not causal)?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by credible? For estimating you do not need the same number of people in each stratum of your covariates (you can weight the treatment difference by the relative number of people in the stratum). See the book by Morgan & Winship or the what if book by Hernan & Robins. Best Stefan

Comment: Thank you Stefan. I mean that if there's only 5 observations in an industry, I might not believe the estimated coeffcients. The same thing if there was 1 program participant and 50 non-participants in one industry, and 50 program participants a 1 non-participant in another industry. It was just based on intuition. I will look at the text you recommend